# Add buttons to Grid in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I want to add two new buttons to the Payment Instructions Grid on the Vendors page.
I would like help to show the new buttons on the grid.

C#:

```
namespace JVDVPayI
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class VendorMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        public PXAction<PX.Objects.AP.VendorR> ApprovePaymentMethod;

        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approve Payment Method")]
        protected void approvePaymentMethod()
        {}

        public PXAction<PX.Objects.AP.VendorR> RejectPaymentMethod;

        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reject Payment Method")]
        protected void rejectPaymentMethod()
        {}
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Screen:
[image]

ASPX:

DataSource extract:

```
  <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" EnableAttributes="true" Visible="True" Width="100%" TypeName="PX.Objects.AP.VendorMaint" PrimaryView="BAccount">
    <CallbackCommands>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="ApprovePaymentMethod" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="grid" />
              <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="RejectPaymentMethod" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="grid" />
    </CallbackCommands>
```

Grid extract

```
    <px:PXGrid ID="grdPaymentDetails" runat="server" Caption="Payment Instructions" SkinID="Attributes" MatrixMode="True" Height="160px" Width="400px">
                    <Levels>
            
      <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="PaymentDetails" DataKeyNames="BAccountID,LocationID,PaymentMethodID,DetailID">
                    <Columns>
                      <px:PXGridColumn DataField="PaymentMethodDetail__descr" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                      <px:PXGridColumn DataField="DetailValue" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                      <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UsrUpdatePaymentInstruction" Width="280" /></Columns>
                    <Layout FormViewHeight="" ></Layout>
                  </px:PXGridLevel>
                </Levels>
                <ActionBar ActionsText="True">
                    <CustomItems>

                           <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Approve Payment Method" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="ApprovePaymentMethod">
                           <AutoCallBack Command="ApprovePaymentMethod" Target="ds" 
                              </AutoCallBack>
                              </px:PXToolBarButton>

                           <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Reject Payment Method" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="RejectPaymentMethod">
                           <AutoCallBack Command="RejectPaymentMethod" Target="ds" > 
                              </AutoCallBack>
                              </px:PXToolBarButton>

                     </CustomItems>
                 </ActionBar>   
       </px:PXGrid>
```

Currently the buttons are showing on top of the page and not on the Grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Since no version was specified, my solution was done against 2021 R1.*

To add your actions to the grid you perform the following steps:

1. Open your customization package
2. Add your screen [AP303000]
3. Open the added screen
4. Find your action (DataSource --> Toolbar --> Form-Specific --> Approve Payment Method)
5. Set the following Properties:

- DependsOnGrid: grdPaymentDetails (this is the id of the grid control you are adding it to)
- Visible: False (this hides it from the top of the screen)

6. Save
7. Find the grid you want to add the action to (Tab --> Payment --> Form --> [2nd] Column --> Group --> Grid: PaymentDetails)
8. Add Control to Grid (Add Controls --> Click and Drag BUTTON onto Grid:PaymentDetails)
9. Select new button ([Grid: PaymentDetails] --> ActionBar-CustomItems --> ToolBarButton
10. Set the following Properties

- AutoCallBack --> Command: ApprovePaymentMethod (this is the action name in code)
- AutoCallBack --> Target: ds (this is the datasource for the action)
- Text: Approve Payment Method (This is the text shown on the button)

11. Save

At this point you would normally be able to repeat steps 4-11 for RejectPaymentMethod then publish and see the actions moved into the grid. For this particular situation there is a catch. The grid you want to add them to has the SkinID of Attributes which doesn't support the action toolbar. You need to override this property with the following steps:

12. Select the target grid (Tab --> Payment --> Form --> [2nd] Column --> Group --> Grid: PaymentDetails)
13. Update the following Property:

- SkinID: Details

14. Save

Now you can publish and see the action shown as desired. Note details will show the standard button set, so you'll likely want to remove those with the following steps

15. Select the target grid (Tab --> Payment --> Form --> [2nd] Column --> Group --> Grid: PaymentDetails)
16. Set the following Properties:

- ActionBar --> Actions --> AddNew --> ToolBarVisible: false
- ActionBar --> Actions --> AdjustColumn --> ToolBarVisible: false
- ActionBar --> Actions --> Delete --> ToolBarVisible: false
- ActionBar --> Actions --> ExportExcel --> ToolBarVisible: false
- ActionBar --> Actions --> Refresh --> ToolBarVisible: false

At this point when you publish your actions will be on the grid (this is assuming you've repeated steps 4-11 for RejectPaymentMethod.)

Comment: This procedure for adding a button to the grid worked for me before. However now when I try, there's an error message on the "LAYOUT PROPERTIES" tab: "Unhandled exception has occurred, your changes have been rolled back: Sequence contains no elements"